# psycopg2.extras.execute_values to insert multiple rows for geometry data

Tags: python, postgis, psycopg2

This is my insert query

```
sql = "INSERT INTO sightings (run_id, geometry, properties)
             VALUES(%s, ST_MakePoint(%s, %s), %s);"
```

1) run_id is an internal uuid

2) geometry - this is geopoint object

3) properties is a JSON object

On running `psycopg2.extras.execute_values(cur, sql, listOfTuples)` I get an error that says:

> the query contains more than one '%s' placeholder'

I realize my mistake around this, but how can I get around it. Is there a way the template parameter can be of any help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, the `template` parameter explained in a documentation for [fast execution helpers](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#fast-exec) does exactly what you need.

> `psycopg2.extras.execute_values(cur, sql, argslist, template=None, page_size=100)`
>
> `template` – the snippet to merge to every item in argslist to compose the query.

Try something like this:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO sightings (run_id, geometry, properties) VALUES %s"
user_id = 1
lnglat = (20.0, 40.0)
props = {"foo": "bar"}

listOfTuples = [(user_id,) + lnglat + (json.dumps(props),)]
# lisftOfTuples = [(1, 20.0, 40.0, '{"foo": "bar"}')]

psycopg2.extras.execute_values(cur, sql, listOfTuples, template='(%s, st_makepoint(%s, %s), %s)')
```

Comment: A wee bit late, but yes this thing worked for me. Thanks @LeventeJuhasz

Comment: what a beauty.. some job of 6355s has done in 114s after using execute_values. Thanks!